# Datetimepicker-DIV in Fullcalendar v4 customButton

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I´d like to show a customized icon on Fullcalendar v4 customButtons and my working datetimepicker-div. I already have a div including a datetimepicker and it works fine. Is it possible to move the entire div into the customButton? Thanks a lot.

HTML

```
<!-- Datetimepicker -->
<div style="float:right;margin: 50px 80px 0px 0px" class='input-group date datepicker_format' id='monatswahl'>
  <input type='hidden' class="form-control" name='monatswahl' />
  <span style="width: 50px;" class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Fullcalendar v4

```
customButtons: {
  datetimepickerButton: {
    icon: 'left-single-arrow',
    click: function(){                    
      $('#monatswahl').data("DateTimePicker").show();
    },
  }
}
```

I´m expecting the following output (datetimepicker to the orange custom button)

[image]

Comment: version 4 of fullcalendar works without jquery. since you're trying to use jquery, did you make sure you have jquery included?

Comment: Hi John, jquery is included and my datepicker works fine. Just want to know if it is possible to change the position of the button to the orange button. Thank you

Comment: in that case, you can just use jquery to replace the button with the html of your datepicker